# EF6 Including references of Collections in Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm setting up a context to be read as follows:

[image]

Now, the last include is a collection and each entity in that collection has a relation (1-to-1) to an entity called `SERVICE_INFO`

How do I include that entity on each `BILL_INFO_DETAIL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just use ,if there is navigation properties in table(BILL_INFO_DETAI):

```
   Include( i=> i.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.SELECT( b => b.SERVICE_INFO ));
```

reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: .ThenInclude is not available for EF6

Comment: I stumbled onto this myself just now. It works. Now I found out there are two more entities (* to 1) after SERVICE_INFO that I need to include as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly. Maybe what you want is the `ThenInclude()`

```
.Include( i=> i.BILL_INFO_DETAIL).ThenInclude(b => b.SERVICE_INFO)
```

Comment: `.ThenInclude` is not available for EF6. It is for ef-core